# How to sum items in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have the following code:

```
dict = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 
    'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 
    'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}

word = 'banana'

for letter in word:
     print dict[letter]
```

I get the following output

```
3
1
1
1
1
```

How can I add these values?

That is how can I print the output as 8

Comment: Using addition? Also, `3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 != 8`

Comment: Don't forget about Double/Triple Letter Scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way that you can sum the items in the list.

```
dict = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1,
    'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10,
    'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}

word = 'banana'
sum = 0
for letter in word:
    sum+=dict[letter]
print sum
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> # Please don't name a variable `dict` -- it overshadows the built-in
>>> dct = { 'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10 }
>>> word = 'banana'
>>> print sum(dct[letter] for letter in word)
8
>>>
```

---

Note that the above solution assumes that all of the characters in `word` can be found in `dct`.  If this isn't always the case, then you can use [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to avoid a `KeyError`:

```
>>> dct = { 'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10 }
>>> word = '$banana1'
>>> print sum(dct.get(letter, 0) for letter in word)
8
>>>
```